# Compiling libtorrent-net

Tags: c++, libtorrent

I am trying to compile libtorrent-net from here https://github.com/vktr/libtorrent-net

After adding the libtorrent 1.06 and boost include directories. I've been getting the following Error in Visual Studio 2017 "*1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libtorrent.lib*'"

Can someone advise how to resolve?

There is no libtorrent.lib file in the source libtorrent folder as to my understanding it is part of the compiled library. As I am adding the raw libtorrent dependencies shouldn't it be creating libtorrent.lib itself?

I am a complete novice in C++ btw so thanks in advance for your help

I know that there is a "newer" libtorrent-net Version in NuGet but it is missing functionalities that this has.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the library paths

Comment: "cannot open input file 'libtorrent.lib" means that this file is missing. That's libtorrent itself, built as a static library. Perhaps you're expected to build that and make it available to the C# bindings build.